Deploy Azure Static Web Apps with Terraform / Python?
I'm building a project with Azure Static Web Apps and the Python CDK for Terraform but I'm unsure how do I get the built app / static files onto the Cloud, I'd like to have my process streamlined so that everything gets done when running cdktf deploy
Using the Static Web Apps CLI this can be done, but it's not a Python library
swa deploy ./prod_static --env=production --deployment-token token

And the Terraform resource doesn't mention any deployment files as far as I can see
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/static_web_app
Is there some sort of Static Web Apps SDK?

Is there any issue when deploying with swa deploy? Do you need to deploy Azure Static Web Apps with Terraform or Python? Either of those is fine

Well yes, swa is a cli utility, I'm looking for something to programmatically deploy it

Are you looking only for a terraform approach. @Filip

Ideally Terraform or Python but alternatives are welcome @Jahnavi

Are you still facing the same issue. @Filip

Yes I am @Jahnavi but I've accepted the workaround of doing this later in the pipeline and not integrating it with cdktf deploy... I'll post my solution

A workaround is to output the api_key (deployment token) from Terraform
TerraformOutput(
    self,
    'swa',
    sensitive=True,
    value=app_web.api_key
)

And use it later in the pipeline, stripped version of a script for my use case
SWA_CLI_DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN=$(terraform -chdir=cdktf.out/stacks/urlshortener-stack output -raw swa) \
npx --yes @azure/static-web-apps-cli deploy ./prod_static --env=production

